# Write GCD's to file

Tags: python, io, greatest-common-divisor

I need to create a program that calculates the GCD of five pairs of numbers and prints them to a text file (OUT1.txt). Each input pair is stored on a separate line in a text file (DATA1.txt), like this:

```
18 24
112 1
43243 333343
20492 87091
3293 979
```

The code I currently have is not outputting anything, though the math operations are correct. My code so far is as follows:

```
outputFile = open('OUT1.txt', 'w+')

n1 = 0
n2 = 0

with open('DATA1.txt', 'w+') as data:
    for line in data:
        twoNums = line.split()
        n1 += int(twoNums[0])
        n2 += int(twoNums[1])
data.close()


def gcd(n1, n2):
    n = min(n1, n2)
    cds = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        while i > 1:
            remainder1 = n1 % i
            remainder2 = n2 % i
            if remainder1 == 0 and remainder2 == 0:
                cds.append(i)
            break
    if not cds:
        outputFile.write('1')
    else:
        outputFile.write(str(max(cds)))


def egcd(n1, n2):
    while n2 != 0:
        (n1, n2) = (n2, n1 % n2)
    outputFile.write(str(n1))
    outputFile.close()

gcd(n1, n2)
egcd(n1, n2)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with this; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a really fragile way of handling files - what if you call `egcd` before `gcd`? You should separate out the calculations and writing their results to files into separate functions, and pass the arguments/return values around appropriately.

Comment: You should open the output file at the same time you open the input file.  You then probably read each line more or less as now, then assign (rather than increment) `n1` and `n2`, then call `gcd(n1, n2)` and print the result to the output file.  The `egcd()` function should go; the `gcd()` function should only do numerical work (no printing).

Comment: I think your problem is that you've opened DATA1.txt with `'w+'` - I'm pretty sure that should just be `'r'`, for read, since you're never writing to it. Also, `data.close()` is completely pointless. `with` blocks automatically close files at their end. Also, it's really weird that you're opening `outputFile` in one scope but then closing it within another... but that probably isn't causing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you want done? It reads a file having a pair of numbers per line and writes their GCD to another file.

```
import math


def main():
    with open('DATA1.txt', 'r') as read, open('OUT1.txt', 'w') as write:
        for line in read:
            print(math.gcd(*map(int, line.split())), file=write)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A file named `OUT1.txt` is created with the following contents:

```
6
1
1
5123
89
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you read and write files should be in the same scope (the main part of the program, and gcd() and egcd()shouldn't access the files.  Have them return the value.

So you would see:

```
gcd1 = gcd(n1, n2)
```

and

```
gcd2 - egcd(n1,n2)
```

Then write those values to your file.

One of the issues is that egcd() closes the output file, which means you can't write to it again.

Another issue is that you only call gcd() and egcd() once.  Those calls should be inside the for-loop within your **with open()** block so that they get called repeatedly for each line in the file.